# JPA: foreign key annotation

Tags: java, database-design, jpa, orm, annotations

I've got two database entities: `Forum` and `Topic`.

`Topic` has `protected long forumId` data member, which indicates of course the `Topic`'s forum.

My question is what annotation to use for this data member?

Comment: You don't need to declare that `forumId` in `Topic`.

Comment: why do you say so? I think it's necessary because I have to know which forum the topic belongs to

Comment: @socksocket I think it's because you can annotate an attribute `Forum`, specifying the id with a `@JoinColumn` annotation, see my answer. ;)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

As Forum has many topics, and a topic belongs to one and only Forum, you probably want to go with a Forum type attribute annotated with [`@ManyToOne`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/ManyToOne.html):

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "forumId")
private Forum forum;
```

**See more:**

[ManyToOne](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ManyToOne) and [JPA mapping](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Mapping)

Comment: but the "problem" in this case is that when you serialize your Topic to XML or JSON (to pass it to a client, for example), the whole Forum object will also be serialized by default... same thing if you upload a topic to your server, you need to pass the whole Topic+Forum objects, you cannot just use the forum id. In some cases, it seems easier to just manually insert the foreign key of the related entity.

Comment: How to solve only the forumId in your example/case??

Comment: @stallion if you configure lazy initialization, you will get only the id (no join required) if you only do `getForum().getId()`. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32220951/just-getting-id-column-value-not-using-join-in-hibernate-object-one-to-many-rela/32223785#32223785

Comment: Those links are amazing. As someone more comfortable with SQL, I feel like I can finally understand what these relationship annotations mean in terms I understand.

Answer (score 6):

As others have answered - 
You should use the `ManyToOne` , and `JoinColumn` annotations. 
Bare in mind , that since JPA is about ORM - Object relational mapping, 
You should reference another object as you would have done "naturally" in Java - i.e via an object and not via its identifier (which is forumId) in your case), 
 This was one of the design consideration between the relations at JPA and Hibernate (previously to JPA).

Answer (score 1):

`@ManyToOne`
As the annotation implies - you have many topics per forum