# Auto populate data in a table having foreign key

Tags: java, mysql, json, spring, hibernate

I have three classes corresponding to three tables in mysql database. My classes are as follows.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="location")
public class Location {

    private Integer locationId;
    private Integer hospitalId;
    private Integer regionId;
    private String locationCode;
    private String locationName;
    private String locationType;


@Entity
@Table(name="hospital_region")
public class HospitalRegion {


    private Integer regionId;
    private Integer hospitalId;
    private String regionCode;
    private String regionName;
    public enum Status{Active,Inactive}
    private Status status;


@Entity
@JsonAutoDetect
@Table(name="hospital_information")
public class HospitalInformation{


    private Integer hospitalId;
    private String shortName;
    private String name;
    private Integer packageId;
    private Date implementationDate;
    private Date validFrom;
    private Date validUpTo;
    private Date lastUpload;
    public enum SubscriptionType{Free,Complimentary,Paid}
    private Integer totalUsers;
```

I am making a **Web Services** for a Hospital Application where one region could have multiple locations(one-to-many) and one hospital could be in multiple regions(one-to-many).

So what I want to do is make a web service that would insert the data into location table.The ideal workflow should be that I shall pass every field in Location class as a `json` object to *insert* a record into the Location table.

My **`Business Logic`** should first check for my `regionId` and `hospitalId` value passed in the `json` object . If the `hospitalId` which is passed corresponds to the value of `regionId` in `region table`, if both correspond, only then data should be saved.

So I need help about how to implement it as a `Business Logic`.Thanks in advance

Comment: Start by reading about JPA and associations, since you obviously missed that part. Then try implementing it by yourself. Then if you have a concrete problem, come back here and ask a question. "I need help" is not a question.

Comment: I am sure its not a question. But Its what everybody here needs. So P.S i need advise/help/solution to this question.

Comment: I think you should change title of your question....it is misguiding other SO user what you really want to ask!!! btw have you performed any example of Spring +Hibernate example yet???

Answer (score 0):

You miss the JPA relationships concept.

Your attributes are not annotated in the 3 classes.

You need to read about:

- @ManyToOne Relation
- @OneToMany Relation
- @OneToOne Relation
- @ManyToMany Relation

**See more:**

[JPA Foreign Key Annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11905956/jpa-foreign-key-annotation)

[JPA Relationships 1](http://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Relationships)

[JPA Relationships 2](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jpa/jpa_entity_relationships.htm)

Comment: Yeah figured out!! Thank you

Comment: If the answer helped you to solve the problem please mark it as best answer in order to help the other users with the same issue! ;)