# Just getting id column value not using join in hibernate object one to many relation

Tags: java, hibernate, join

I'm using hibernate 4+.

I have two sample tables.

Table A

```
public class A {
  @Id
  private int id;

  @OneToMany(fetch=LAZY)
  private List<B> list;

  // skip getter&setter
}
```

Table B

```
public class B {
  @Id
  private int id;

  @ManyToOne(fetch=LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name="b_id")
  private A a;

  // skip getter&setter
}
```

Table A(1) - (n)Table B Relation

Can I just get A's id in object B not using join? Something like:

```
int aid = b.getA().getId(); // b is instance of B;
```

Although I can use int value instead of A when I declare class B.
But another service layer use A with join.

Can I just get id(fk) value?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, because proxies contain the id anyway. To get the id of an `A` proxy without initializing it, first declare the id to be accessed via property:

```
@Entity
public class A {
  @Id
  @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
  private int id;

  @OneToMany(fetch=LAZY)
  private List<B> list;

  public int getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
  }
}
```

Then, just read the id:

```
b.getA().getId();
```

Changing access type for the id is necessary because if you use field access, Hibernate does not distinguish `getId()` method from other ordinary methods (which trigger proxy initialization when invoked).

Answer (score 9):

You can define two fields in B, one representing the relationship, and the other just the column:

```
  @ManyToOne(fetch=LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name="b_id")
  private A a;

  @Column(name="b_id", updatable=false,insertable=false) //Or correct column
  private int a_id;
```

This way you can access entity A or just A's id from entity B.

Comment: Does this mean there is only 1 column in the DB "b_id" and this tricks JPA into allowing b.a_id in the JPA query?

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use this post : [property access strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593722/hibernate-one-to-one-getid-without-fetching-entire-object)

It is said that the lazy loading will not be triggered if you only access id