# Hibernate: foreign key error on insert when referencing foreign key in entity

Tags: java, hibernate

I have the following entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "calendar")
public class Calendar {
    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(name = "id", columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)")
    private UUID id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "owner", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private OrganizerUser owner;
    ...
}
```

If I insert an object of that class into the table, everything works fine. However, when I add the following to the entity:

```
@Column(name = "owner", updatable = false, insertable = false)
private UUID ownerId;
```

I get the following error:

```
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`organizer`.`calendar`, CONSTRAINT `FK3f7d9mholcykdaygm3bnwhwg7` FOREIGN KEY (`owner`) REFERENCES `user_info` (`id`))
```

Is it possible to have a reference to the foreign key in this scenario? If I omit the reference and just do `owner.getId()`, will the OrganizerUser object be loaded?

Comment: Yes if you access owner.getId() the OrganizerUser object will be fetched from the database. 

In the second case do you set the owner or only the ownerId?

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32223785/4754790) regarding the accessing of id field on a proxy.

Comment: In the second case, I set only the owner