# Foreign key constraint issue for One-to-Many unidirectional relation

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc, foreign-keys

I have `Employee` (parent) and `Emp_Contacts` (child). Only `Employee` class has unidirectional mapping.

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.Digits;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;

@Entity
@Table(name="EMPLOYEE")
public class Employee {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private int id;

  @Size(min=3, max=50)
  @Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false)
  private String name;

...

  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name = "emp_id")
  private Set<Emp_Contacts> contacts;

...getters and setters...
```

My `Emp_Contacts` is as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Emp_Contacts")
public class Emp_Contacts implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private int emp_contact_id;

  @NotNull
  @Column(name = "emp_id")
  private long emp_id;

....
```

DB table has not null FK constraint for `emp_contacts` table on `emp_id`.

1. If I remove above constraint then `persist(employee)` will persists employee and corresponding emp_contacts.
2. With FK constraint I get below error:

   `MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails`

I searched on internet and found this link https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=995514

But if I put nullable in `Employee`:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "emp_id", nullable = false)
private Set<Emp_Contacts> contacts
```

my server does not even start, I get below error:

```
Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.cynosure.model.Emp_Contacts
column: emp_id (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Employee` is the association owning side (because it's the only side). That way foreign key is always updated separately from inserting the associated `Emp_Contacts` instances, so it must be nullable.

The recommended solution is to make the association bidirectional and make the many side the owner of the association:

```
public class Employee {
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "employee")
  private Set<Emp_Contacts> contacts;
}

public class Emp_Contacts {
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "emp_id", nullable = false)
  private Employee employee;
}
```

This way the foreign key can be not-nullable and you avoid the costs of an extra statement to update the foreign key because the foreign key value is set when inserting `Emp_Contacts`.

Also, you will always have the associated employee id in the `Emp_Contacts` instance (what seems to be your intention). You don't have to load the employee from the database in order to access its id because the association can be declared lazy (as in the example above) and Hibernate will generate a proxy containing only the id. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32220951/just-getting-id-column-value-not-using-join-in-hibernate-object-one-to-many-rela/32223785#32223785) for more information.

Another benefit is that you can navigate the association from both sides when needed (useful also in HQL/JPQL queries).

If you nevertheless want to use your original solution (unidirectional association with only plain foreign key value on the many side), then make the join column nullable and make the `emp_id` property `insertable = false, updatable = false`, because Hibernate will automatically update the mapped foreign key column when maintaining the association on the `Employee` side:

```
@Column(name = "emp_id, insertable = false, updatable = false")
private long emp_id;
```

Comment: worked like a charm! you made my day.  I will also change the association to bidirectional.

Comment: Are you getting emp_id in the entity object from the child table? In my case, because of bi directional one-to-many  mapping foreign key is being stored in the child table, but not reflected in the entity object. Can you please help

Comment: I need it in unidirectional relation. can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

1. When Hibernate has to delete a child value, it tries to nullify the foreign key. You should not have to remove the constraint on the Foreign Key to persist changes to Emp_Contacts. Instead, on the JoinColumn annotation, set updatable = false. This tells Hibernate to NOT change foreign key values.
2. Next, set orphanRemoval = true on the OneToMany annotation. You would think Hibernate defaults orphanRemoval to true but it does not :(. Our team fought with this silly behavior for a couple days. Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure here, but you could try to remove the

```
@NotNull
@Column(name = "emp_id")
private long emp_id;
```

from class `Emp_Contacts`. To me it looks like Hibernate complains about the duplicate mapping of `emp_id`, and you already mapped that column in `Employee`.